# QT Visual Studio plugin fails automatic moc with non-standard header extensions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5, moc

I am currently trying to port a very large project to QT. Many of the headers in this project use the file extension .hh . I would ideally like to avoid having to rename all of these files, but it appears to be causing some issues for the QT Visual Studio plugin. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and QT 5.5.

I have set up a trivial project to test this problem. If i define a class in a .h file that inherits from QObject and contains the Q_OBJECT macro the Custom Build instructions are automatically added to the files properties and moc'd files are automatically generated. If i rename the file to have a .hh extension no Custom Build instructions are generated and no moc'd files are generated.

I have attempted adding hh to the "Filter" property of the folder/filter containing my header files. This seems to result in the Custom Build instructions being applied to the headers, the correct files being generated by MOC, but not automatically included into the solution. This results the build failing with linker errors.

I would be surprised if this wasn't configurable some how. Has anyone had any success with custom file extensions before?